# How to import dataframe-js into Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dataframe-js

I have used the http link to import the package:

```
var d3Url = "https://gmousse.github.io/dataframe-js/dist/dataframe.js";
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(d3Url).getContentText());
```

But when I do `const df = new DataFrame(company_df[1], company_df[0])`, it gives a `Reference Error: DataFrame is not defined`.

I have also tried to put `var DataFrame = dfjs.DataFrame;` at the top. But, no luck.

How can I correctly import the package?

Comment: I put the `eval` on the same file `new DataFrame`, it works! But when I put it in another file, it does not work.

Comment: Consider adding a answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put

```
var Url = "https://gmousse.github.io/dataframe-js/dist/dataframe.min.js";
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText());
```

in the same file of `var DataFrame = dfjs.DataFrame;`

It works although I don't know the reasons.